# EF Core migration failing because of IPublishEndpoint

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, migration

As the title says I got a failing migration that happens when I add a bit of code using the IPublishEndpoint. As soon as I comment that part it works again.

The code that is getting commented:

```
private async Task PublishTestDataAsync(Guid testId, Guid testLearnerId, string domain)
        {
            var test = await _testRepository.GetAsync(testId);
            using CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            await _publishEndpoint.Publish<TestResult>(new
            {
                TestLearnerId = testLearnerId,
                Domain = domain,
                IsProdLearnositySite = test?.IsProdEnvironment
            }, tokenSource.Token);
        }
```

And this is the error:

```
An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: The entry point exited without ever building an IHost.
No application service provider was found.
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Found DbContext 'TestContext'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Unable to create an object of type 'TestContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[NFER.ENOT.Tests.Repositories.Configuration.TestContext]' while attempting to activate 'NFER.ENOT.Tests.Repositories.Configuration.TestContext'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass21_4.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass21_4.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Unable to create an object of type 'TestContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```